# How to temporarily escape an 'alignedat' environment nested inside an 'align*' environment?

Tags: equations, align, alignment, alignat

This is my output:

[image: Output]

The problem, of course, is with the misplaced third line. What should happen is this:

- The four left-hand equal signs ought to be aligned;
- additionally minus signs and plus signs from the second and third lines should be aligned, respectively;
- this additional alignment should *not* affect first or fourth lines.

Here is what I tried (full working example simplified document, so you may copy):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage[estonian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newgeometry{margin=2.5cm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{upgreek}{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ppi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`p}

\newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\Int}[3]{\int\limits_{#1}^{#2}{#3}\, \mathrm{d}x}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
                a_k &= \f{2}{\ppi}\Int{0}{\ppi}{f(x)} = \f{2}{\ppi}\Int{0}{\f{\ppi}{2}}{\left(
                \f{\ppi}{2}-x\right)} + \f{2}{\ppi}\Int{\f{\ppi}{2}}{\ppi}{\ppi} = \\
                &=\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
                    \f{2}{\ppi} \f{\ppi}{2} \left(\f{\ppi}{2}\right)-&
                    \f{2}{\ppi} \f{1}{2} \left(\f{\ppi}{2}\right)^2 +& 
                    \f{2}{\ppi}\ppi\left(\ppi-\f{\ppi}{2}\right)=\\
                    &= \f{\ppi}{2} -& \f{\ppi}{4} +& 2\f{\ppi}{2} =
                \end{alignedat}\\
                &=\f{5}{4}\ppi
            \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The part that is of interest to this question, of course, is the following subpart of the above:

```
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
                a_k &= \f{2}{\ppi}\Int{0}{\ppi}{f(x)} = \f{2}{\ppi}\Int{0}{\f{\ppi}{2}}{\left(
                \f{\ppi}{2}-x\right)} + \f{2}{\ppi}\Int{\f{\ppi}{2}}{\ppi}{\ppi} = \\
                &=\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
                    \f{2}{\ppi} \f{\ppi}{2} \left(\f{\ppi}{2}\right)-&
                    \f{2}{\ppi} \f{1}{2} \left(\f{\ppi}{2}\right)^2 +& 
                    \f{2}{\ppi}\ppi\left(\ppi-\f{\ppi}{2}\right)=\\
                    &= \f{\ppi}{2} -& \f{\ppi}{4} +& 2\f{\ppi}{2} =
                \end{alignedat}\\
                &=\f{5}{4}\ppi
            \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I believe I understand what the problem is. Have a look at the penultimate line inside the `alignedat` environment. There I have written `&=`; unfortunately, the line break `\\` from the line previous only applies to the `alignedat` environment. It does not reach the `align*` environment.

So ideally this `\\` should have a dual role, signalling `alignedat` and `align*` simultaneously. Simply put, can I do something like this (cf. `\insertcommand{}`):

```
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
                a_k &= \f{2}{\ppi}\Int{0}{\ppi}{f(x)} = \f{2}{\ppi}\Int{0}{\f{\ppi}{2}}{\left(
                \f{\ppi}{2}-x\right)} + \f{2}{\ppi}\Int{\f{\ppi}{2}}{\ppi}{\ppi} = \\
                &=\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
                    \f{2}{\ppi} \f{\ppi}{2} \left(\f{\ppi}{2}\right)-&
                    \f{2}{\ppi} \f{1}{2} \left(\f{\ppi}{2}\right)^2 +& 
                    \f{2}{\ppi}\ppi\left(\ppi-\f{\ppi}{2}\right)=\\
                    \insertcommand{\\ &=} \f{\ppi}{2} -& \f{\ppi}{4} +& 2\f{\ppi}{2} =
                \end{alignedat}\\
                &=\f{5}{4}\ppi
            \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

so that the `\\ &=` is sent to `align`, and after that, `alignedat` continues?

I am very much hoping that such a minor tweak suffices; but other answers are welcome, too (if they do not require (much) manual usage of `\!`-s and so on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want proper (horizontal) alignment across elements within the equation, you can use the measuring capabilities of [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`. All elements with the same `<tag>` will be put in a box of maximum width (with an optional `<align>`ment; default is `c`entred):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\Int}[3]{\int\limits_{#1}^{#2}{#3}\, \mathrm{d}x}

\let\ppi\pi

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a_k &= \f{2}{\ppi} \Int{0}{\ppi}{f(x)} 
    = \f{2}{\ppi} \Int{0}{\f{\ppi}{2}}{\Bigl( \f{\ppi}{2} - x \Bigr)} 
      + \f{2}{\ppi} \Int{\f{\ppi}{2}}{\ppi}{\ppi} \\
   &= \eqmakebox[first]{$\displaystyle \underbrace{\f{2}{\ppi} \f{\ppi}{2} \Bigl( \f{\ppi}{2} \Bigr)}$}
    - \eqmakebox[second]{$\displaystyle \underbrace{\f{2}{\ppi} \f{1}{2} \Bigl( \f{\ppi}{2} \Bigr)^2}$}
    + \eqmakebox[third]{$\displaystyle \underbrace{\f{2}{\ppi} \ppi \Bigl( \ppi - \f{\ppi}{2} \Bigr)}$} \\
   &= \eqmakebox[first]{$\displaystyle \f{\ppi}{2}$} 
    - \eqmakebox[second]{$\displaystyle \f{\ppi}{4}$} 
    + \eqmakebox[third]{$\displaystyle 2 \f{\ppi}{2}$} \\
   &= \f{5}{4} \ppi
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this approach! So here the minus signs and plus signs are not aligned directly; rather their alignment is the inescapeable by-product of aligning the boxes. Is that correct?

Comment: @LinearChristmas: Correct. It's a convenient by-product of correctly sizing with boxes.

Comment: I suspect this approach will therefore work like a charm in this particular case (and, in fact, for most of the document I'm working on). On a possible downside, there might be (not sure atm) a situation which calls for similar alignment inside `align´ *but* for which there are no clear well-definable boxes. Great answer still. (I'll probably accept an answer somewhere around 48 hours from now).

Comment: @LinearChristmas: True. There might be different cases where a box-alignment is not needed, at which point one could use `aligned` (or similar). This is a convenient approach with your use-case. You can do it manually as well... that is, measure the boxes yourself and then use that in your code. [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) just makes this usage convenient by automating the measurement. It uses (La)TeX's `\label`-`\ref`-like system, storing content in your `.aux`. So, any change in the widest element will require two compilations to settle.